# Counting the nodes for game over

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

In my game I have three balls and I want the game to be over when there is only one left. I have this code below to make it end when there's none left. I tried some code below to make it so it ends when theres one left but it's not working properly. Any ideas on how to solve this?

This is the code I'm using to determine if there isn't any balls left:

```
-(BOOL)isGameWon {
for (SKNode* node in self.children)
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"ball"])
        return NO;
return YES;
}
```

This is the code I tired to use to check if there's only one left:

```
-(BOOL)isGameWon {
for (SKNode* node in self.children)
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"ball"])
        node = 1;
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
-(BOOL)isGameWon 
{
    NSInteger ballsCount = 0;
    for (SKNode* node in self.children)
    { 
        if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"ball"])
        {
            ballsCount +=1;
        }
        if(ballsCount > 1) return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```